# Can't append objects to an array inside a closure

Tags: ios, swift, api

I'm new in swift and I got the idea of building an app that shows live live scores.
So for that I'm using Alamofire framework to make HTTP requests by using a closure.

To represent each single match score and result I created the following class called "Score":

```
class Score {

var homeTeamName : String = ""
var visitorTeamName : String = ""
var matchScore : String = ""
var matchTime : String = ""}
```

In the LiveScoresViewController I declared and initialized a global empty collection of type "Scores" where the live scores will be stocked

```
var scoresArray : [Score] = [Score]()
```

Then I create two methods:

- getLiveScore : to make the http request

```
func getLiveScores(url : String) {
        Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON { response in

            if response.result.isFailure {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error Occured", message: "Please check your connection or restart the application", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel)

                alert.addAction(alertAction)
            }

            else {
                let liveScoresJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                self.updateLiveScore(json: liveScoresJSON)
            }
        }
    }
```

- updateLiveScore : to parse the JSON result and represent it

```
func updateLiveScore(json : JSON) {
        let size = json["result"].count

        for index in 0..<size {
            let match = Score()
            match.homeTeamName = json["result"][index]["event_home_team"].string!
            match.visitorTeamName = json["result"][index]["event_away_team"].string!
            match.matchScore = json["result"][index]["event_final_result"].string!
            match.matchTime = json["result"][index]["event_status"].string!

            scoresArray.append(match)
        }
    }
```

getLiveScore method is called in the viewDidLoad() function but the "scoresArray" remain empty even if the request result are not! I tried to pass the collection in the methods parameters but I realized that I can't modify it in swift, and not like java, parameters are constants.

Comment: How did you know `scoresArray` is empty? Did you look at it through a debugger? Did you make sure to inspect it after the response is received?

Comment: @Sweeper after I called the 'getLiveScore' method, I print the size of the collection and it was empty (output : 0)

Comment: If you call it like that, 0 _is_ the expected output, because the response has not been received yet. Requesting things on the internet takes time. To get a non-zero output, you can either print it in `didSet` of `scoresArray`, or just after the call to `updateLiveScore`.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, the collection is not empty after I call updateLiveScore, but I need to represent the scores in a table view, my problem is I m not familiar with closures so appended value in the closure are no longer available outside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First** it's better to use `Codable` to decode the response

**Second** the call to the api is asynchronous that's why it's empty inside `viewDidLoad` so you need to refresh the table/collection inside the closure after you append the data to the array